# Change data of a button according to selected Row in TableView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, storyboard, ibaction, uitableview

I'm trying to change the destination of a button using the selected Row of a tableViewCell.

How would I do that? I know how to change the text in a UILabel. Would it be something like that? I'm using this in my MainView to get to the DetailView:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"toDetail"]) {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    DetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    destViewController.nameIdentity = [nameData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
}
```

And in my DetailView.m:

```
{
[super viewDidLoad];
nameLabel.text = nameIdentity;
}
```

I used a NSArray for my data. Is that the correct way to go for the numbers as well?

I`m using X-Code 4.6, Objective-C, Storyboard.

**Could this work? (I can't test it on an actual Device yet)**

MainView.m

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"toDetail"]) {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    DetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    destViewController.numberIdentity = [numberData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
numberData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:/*1*/@"5552525",/*2*/@"5553456", nil];
}
```

DetailView.m

```
-(IBAction)callCell {
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]
 openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:numberIdentity]];
}
```

How can I fire a message to the debugger?

Comment: There is still a long way to go given the code you include in the question, which is very little. Have you implemented the table view delegate didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: Sorry. Forgot. I`m using prepareForSegue. I did edit my post.
If i do understand it correctly, the prepareForSegue is an alternative to didSelectAtIndexPath.

Comment: It is not an alternative. The prepareForSegue is called right before the segue is performed. So you still need to call performSegueWithIdentifier to perform segue programatically unless you create the segue directly from a table view cell in the storyboard. Is the prepareForSegue called if you set a breakpoint there?

Comment: I`m sorry. I don`t know what you mean by breakpoint.
I made a Push Segue to the DetailView in the Storyboard.
By Code i follow the identifier of the Segue.

Maybe you could give me a hint on how to approach this.

Comment: I added a possible Solution, but can`t test it because i can`t use an actual device yet. What you think?